# Only a portion of multiple non-returning function calls run concurrently with async/await

Tags: rust, async-await

I have a test case that attempts to run async methods concurrently.  My code attempts to start. 50 of these, but when I run it, only about 12 print the statement at the beginning of the async method.

What do I need to do to get them all running concurrently?

```
use futures::executor;
use futures::future;
use async_std;

async fn _spin(i: u32) {
    println!("starting {}", i);
    loop {
        //do work
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut futures = vec![];
    for i in 0..50 {
        futures.push(_spin(i));
    }
    let handles = futures.into_iter().map(async_std::task::spawn).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let joined = future::join_all(handles);
    let _results = executor::block_on(joined);
}
```

output.  Note the ones that get run are seemingly randomly picked.

```
starting 0
starting 7
starting 12
starting 2
starting 11
starting 16
starting 10
starting 17
starting 1
starting 15
starting 3
starting 13
```

Comment: What does "do work" entail? Do you await anything inside it that would eventually suspend?

Comment: Wild guess: your PC has 12 cores (or 6 cores and hyperthreading)

Comment: @user4815162342 The work involves literally nothing in this case.  Tried with printing a line, etc.  In the real software it's sending some stuff to an async channel, but as I tried with just a println, I don't think the work is the issue.  Otherwise I think the first one would block.

Comment: @Jmb - you are correct.  12 hyperthreads on the machine in question.  So I guess the default behavior is to create a threadpool with the same number of threads as hyperthreads?   Looking at `async_std::task::spawn` I don't see a way to configure this.

Comment: The work _is_ the issue; since you're never awaiting anything, you're never suspending, and you're not giving other tasks a chance to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a "blocking" function, ie. a function that does a lot of work without calling `await`, then you should use [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.5.0/async_std/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) instead of `spawn` so that the function will get a dedicated thread. Otherwise tasks are spawned depending on the executor. In `async-std`, the default executor is a thread pool with at most as many threads as logical cores. You can however spawn tasks on other executors, including thread pools with a different number of threads:

```
futures::executor::ThreadPool;
let pool = ThreadPool::builder()
    .pool_size (2)
    .create()
    .unwrap();
pool.spawn_ok (async { /* do work */ });
/* Wait for tasks to complete */
```